# \[NSOperationQueue currentQueue\] vs \[\[NSOperationQueue alloc\] init\]

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsoperationqueue

Now I can use both to process tasks from operation objects?

So what is different ?

BR,

Answer (score 0):

`currentQueue` returns the queue that started the current operation. So, if there isn't a current operation then there is no queue.

`alloc init` creates a new queue.

> I can use both to process tasks from operation objects?

You add operations to the queue and the queue manages the processing of the operations. You either want to create a new queue yourself or re-use a queue you created earlier and stored (in a property).